# Change firstname and familyname colors in moderncv classic & add a line below that & put the title below the line

Tags: color, moderncv

I'm using the `classic` theme of `moderncv` (version 1.1) but would like to tweak a bit the header (but I'm too dumb to do that).

1. How to make name/family name colors look like in the `casual` theme (i.e. the first name in grey and the last name in black).
2. Ideally I would also like to add a line below my name and photo and put the title BELOW the line.

I know I'm asking a lot, I browsed the questions but didn't find the way to do that.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%!TEX encoding = Windows Latin 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{9cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Emilie} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{bla bla bla blaaa $\&$ bla blaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\address{1, rue des yyyyyyy}{34000  Montpellier, France}
\email{xx.yy@gmail.com}
\mobile{+(33) 00 00 00 00}
\extrainfo{26 years old}
%\birthdate{26 years old}

%\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[70pt][0pt]{em-d.jpg} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{bla bla bla blaaa $\&$ bla}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\cventry{2007--2010}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 7.5}}{Specialized in Commerce}

\section{Masters Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

\clearpage

\recipient{HR Department}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} % Letter recipient
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, it would be nice to put the information you just gave together as a little code example. That means less effort for potential helpers and higher chances of a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a redefinition of `\makecvtitle`; for example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%!TEX encoding = Windows Latin 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{9cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\textcolor{color2!50}{\@firstname}\ \textcolor{color2}{\@lastname}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}}}%
    \par\vskip-3ex{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  \par
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\bigskip\titlestyle{\raggedright\@title}}%
  \par\bigskip}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Emilie} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{bla bla bla blaaa $\&$ bla blaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\address{1, rue des yyyyyyy}{34000  Montpellier, France}
\email{xx.yy@gmail.com}
\mobile{+(33) 00 00 00 00}
\extrainfo{26 years old}
%\birthdate{26 years old}

%\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[70pt][0pt]{picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{bla bla bla blaaa $\&$ bla}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\cventry{2007--2010}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 7.5}}{Specialized in Commerce}

\section{Masters Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

\clearpage

\recipient{HR Department}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} % Letter recipient
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have few errors though when I try to compile:  `Undefined control sequence.
\makecvtitle ... \phonesdetails {}\collectionloop 
                                                  {phones}{\protected@edef \...`

Comment: and the same error with "csname", "endcsname", "socialsdetails", or "addresscountry". Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Emilie You are using an outdated version of the `moderncv` bundle. Please update the packages. (If that's not possible, please let me know which version of `moderncv` are you using, so I can produce an answer wich will work with your version).